# Creating custom layer using React leaflet V3

Tags: typescript, leaflet, openstreetmap, react-leaflet, react-leaflet-v3

I want to create a custom helper div layer on the map on a button click or mouse-over over the button. The button is also a custom control button on the map. Here is the example [control button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68414583/custom-button-on-the-leaflet-map-with-react-leaflet-version3/68415125#68415125)

My custom layer will provide map related information. The whole functionality should work like the React leaflet [Layers control](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-layers-control),

That is, upon a mouse-hover/click on a custom control div/button a custom layer should popup with map related information.

I created the custom div layer. However, I'm facing two problems.

1. I couldn't position it on the map. I tried first with "bottomleft" option. It didn't work. My actual intention is to position just near the help-control-button exactly like "Layers control" from React.leaflet documentation.
2. Right now, the code is listening to any "click" event on the map. I want to make it specific to my control button. How to make the connection between the control layer and control button ? How to pass this control button to the layer ?

Any help is much appreciated. Here is my code as below.

> custom layer component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { useMap } from "react-leaflet";
import L, { LeafletMouseEvent, Map } from "leaflet";

class CustomMapHelpGuide extends React.Component<{},{props:any}>{

helpDesc:any;
createDescLayer(opts:any){
    const DescHelp = L.Layer.extend({
        onAdd: (map: Map) => {
            const helpDesc = L.DomUtil.create('div','');
            helpDesc.innerHTML = "this is a map description div";
            this.helpDesc = helpDesc;
            map.getPanes().overlayPane.appendChild(this.helpDesc);
            map.on('click',this.testFunc, this);
            return helpDesc;
        }
    });

    return new DescHelp(); //I tried to pass the "opts" parameter but it is throwing error saying it doesn't expect an argument
}

testFunc(){
    console.log("layer is implemenetd"); //upon click anywhere in the map this is getting printed on console
    
}

componentDidMount() {
    const { map} = this.props as any;
    const layer = this.createDescLayer({ position: 'bottomleft' });
   // map.addLayer(layer);
    layer.addTo(map);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this.helpDesc.remove();
  }

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

function withMap(Component : any) {
  return function WrappedComponent(props : any) {
    const map = useMap();
    return <Component {...props} map={map} />;
  };
}

export default withMap(CustomMapHelpGuide);
```

> Here is how it is called for the time being,

```
<MapContainer
        center={customPosition}
        zoom={9}
        zoomControl={false}
        >
             <DescriptionButton/>
            <CustomMapDescLayer/>

            <TileLayer
                attribution="Map tiles by Carto, under CC BY 3.0. Data by OpenStreetMap, under ODbL."
                url="https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />
        </MapContainer>
```

Comment: Why are you extending L.Layer instead of L.Control?  Are you trying to create a little info-div that appears in the upper right corner of the map, in line with the other controls?  Or do you want more of a modal?  If this is ultimately a modal-type functionality with information in it, why does this need to be a leaflet feature at all? Why not just a modal that is completely separate from the Map component?  Not all UI features of a leaflet application have to be leaflet components.  If you want a L.Control type feature, try extending L.Control

Comment: Hello @SethLutske thank you for reaching out. Your answer gave some food for thought for me. Actually, I want to create an info-div but that should appear on button control click/hover just like https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-layers-control/. Reading the documentation https://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-3-controls.html of layer and controls I felt the button should be control and the popup info div should be layer. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @SethLutske : Obviously, a modal is another option. But if I create the info div as a control then how shall connect it to my button control so that on button click this info div appears ?